# appengine python shutdown hook

Tags: python, google-app-engine, hook, instance

I´m looking for a way to create a shutdown hook for instances (not backend) on Google App Engine. Does anyone know a way to implement this? Will python "atexit" module work?

```
atexit.register(func[, *args[, **kargs]])
```

Comment: I don't believe there is a public api. I had to resort to exhausting all ram to close an instance from within the instance. Having said that you can now stop an instance through the console so some mechanism exists.

Comment: What sort of things are you hoping to run on exit? Generally your application should not care about specific instances.

Comment: I was thinking of storing some in memory data but I will take another approach. Thanks doh!

Answer (score 0):

There is a tiny example in the Shudown section on the GAE Modules page, but the tag is not working properly:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Shutdown

It's right above this section:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Instance_uptime

Comment: Oops - year old Q, how did I even get to it?